# Tomcat secure Websocket

Tags: sockets, tomcat, ssl, https, websocket

I'm having trouble to get a WebSocket connection via TLS on a Tomcat 8.

I have set up the following connectors:

```
<Connector  port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443"
/>

<Connector  port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
            keystorefile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
/>
```

Inside a standard Tomcat servlet named "socket" I have used the @ServerEndpoint annotation on a class to create a WebSocket endpoint. So an abridged version looks like the following:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/echo")
public class EchoServer {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        //
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        //
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        //
    }
}
```

On my client side I have a html script connecting a WebSocket:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/socket/echo");
```

When I connect to http://localhost:8080/socket everything works fine. I can open the socket connection and pass messages back and forth.

Using https://localhost:8443/socket I can connect to the servlet, but I cannot open the socket connection as it is an unsafe operation. I then tried changing the connection string to:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/socket/echo");
```

but like this I cannot get any connection.

When I look at the Tomcat docs (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) I do not understand what I need to change - I see some mention of SSL_CONTEXT and the like, but I cannot find any example how this is used (I have no ClientEndpointConfig anyhow, since that's the browser?).

Could someone point me in the direction of a solution?
Why is the connection that's working fine on the http port not working on the https port?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Anyone a clue? I kinda seem to have the same problem and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We did solve the problem, but it involved a lot of fiddling and I'm not sure what did the trick. The code above is correct. I think, all we had to do in the end was updating to a new version of Tomcat? If it is a possibility, you could also put your Tomcat behind a nginx listening on https and forward the Websocket to the http Tomcat port [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) - which is a common setup in our case.